# How to count finished courses into 1 and count all those who finished the training

Tags: postgresql

> I have 5 mandatory courses which is [ Python, Java, Kotlin, SQL, React ]. And I have different tables

> Table name : dbo.course

| course_id | course_name | mandatory | category_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | python | yes | 20 |
| 2 | java | yes | 20 |
| 3 | kotlin | yes | 20 |
| 4 | sql | yes | 20 |
| 5 | react | yes | 20 |
| 6 | c++ | no | 21 |
| 7 | git | no | 22 |
| 8 | vb.net | no | 23 |

> table name : Table name : dbo.category which is linked to dbo.course

| category_id | category_name |
| --- | --- |
| 20 | Dev |
| 21 | Bridge |
| 22 | PM |
| 23 | Bas |

> Table name : dbo.attendance    (p = present ,  a = absent)

| participant_id | status | course_id | log_in_date | log_out_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | p | 1 | july 2021 | july 2021 |
| 1 | p | 2 | july 2021 | july 2021 |
| 1 | p | 3 | july 2021 | july 2021 |
| 1 | p | 4 | july 2021 | july 2021 |
| 1 | p | 5 | july 2021 | july 2021 |
| 2 | p | 1 | july 2021 | july 2021 |
| 3 | a | 6 | null | null |
| 4 | a | 8 | null | null |
| 5 | p | 1 | july 2021 | july 2021 |
| 5 | p | 2 | july 2021 | july 2021 |
| 5 | p | 3 | july 2021 | july 2021 |
| 5 | p | 4 | july 2021 | july 2021 |
| 5 | p | 5 | july 2021 | july 2021 |

> if the participant finished all the mandatory courses then it will count as 1 and if not, it will not count unless he/she finish the training. I want the output something like this : Assume that there is 5 participant that finished the training in August 2021 and 10 participant in September 2021

select date,count(participant), count(*)

| date | participant | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| july 2021 | 2 | 2 |
| august 2021 | 5 | 7 |
| september 2021 | 10 | 17 |

Comment: Hi! Can you post your `CREATE` and `INSERT` statement for all the tables?

Comment: I downloaded it, and unfortunately I can't run it because it is not mysql, maybe tag only those appropriate tags.

Comment: Welcome to the SO community. Please take a look at [ask]. You have requested *5 participant that finished the training in August 2021 and 10 participant in September 2021*. Sorry, but that is not how it works. If that is  the result you want then you must provide the data to accomplish it. Further if you actually want dates then you need to actually supply dates.  So `date '2021-01-07'` instead or month name and year or does you data literally contain 'july 2021'. Also post the actual table definition (DDL), as text - **no images**.